# error plotting function using matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plotting a function but I receive an error and since I'm a newbie I don't know how to fix it.

```
 f=-10:0.001:10;
 >> w=1/sqrt(4+(2*pi*f)^2);
 ??? Error using ==> mpower
 Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
 To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the **matrix** power operator, `mpower`. The syntax `A^n` attempts to raise the (square) matrix `A` to the `n`th power. This will obviously fail if `A` is not a square matrix (in your example, it is a vector).

Since your username includes `eng` and you're posting about MATLAB, I assume that you are an engineering student - your introductory math course should have covered matrix math, and why `A * A` is only defined for square `A`.

You actually want the **scalar** operator `.^`, as in `A.^n`. This raises each element of `A` to the `n`th power.

Comment: also by `w` you probably mean angular frequency `omega`. Just because `\omega` looks like a `w` doesn't mean you should name it that way. ;)

Comment: Well I tried as you suggested me but I receive this error: Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Same kind of mistake. Consider, for example, `f = -10:1:10; g = 1 / f`. Please read the documentation for [arithmetic operators.](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) First one was free, but you get to figure the second one out yourself. ;)

Comment: In general, always use the dotted version of a math operator unless you actually mean to do matrix math.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is exactly where the error message says you have a mistake.  Since you are a newbie at Matlab, and I am vicious, I think that it will be useful to your learning to figure this one out for yourself. Read the last line of the error message carefully.