# Calculating power with ^

Tags: matlab, function, graph, exponent

I am trying to model a graph as shown in the attached image. The equation for which I am modelling is also shown in the image.

[image: Click Here For the Image]

My codings are,

```
sigmafu=1660; 
phi=0.0:0.01:90;
e=2.7183; %I searched on internet to find e value of Euler number and I 
%found this. 
%Dont know whether MATLAB bydefault has value of e, like MATLAB has value 
%pi.
pw= (-0.3)*phi*(180/180);
F=sigmafu*(0)* 2.7183^(pw);
plot (phi,F)
```

I am getting the following error by using the above codings:

> Error using  ^. Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix. To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
>   Error in myeqsetlin (line 126): F=sigmafu*(0)* 2.7183^(pw);

Can anyone help me correct the code? Also, does MATLAB have the default value of e (Euler's number), if so how can I use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error plotting function using matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771398/error-plotting-function-using-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value for e with exp(1). meaning e^1.

```
sigmafu = 1660; 
phi = 0.0:0.01:90;
pw = -0.3*phi*pi/180;
F = sigmafu*exp(pw);
plot(phi,F)
```

Comment: If I use .^ instead of ^ I get a straight horizontal line in the graph at 0. It still does not solve the problem

Comment: that surprises you? you multiply by (0), what do you expect?

Comment: Oh, and multiply by (180/180) does not contribute much to your code. You want to multiply by (pi/180). Conversion from degrees to radian.

Comment: `exp(1).^pw` should be written as just `exp(pw)` ([the `exp` function already has elementwise behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html)).